# connect the 2 path using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have attach a jpeg that has a 2 path disconnected.  I would to like to connect it.  Pls advice

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Can you give some more details about what you are trying to do? I see the graphic, but are those lines actually paths? Do you mean how you can recreate the 'bridge' between them so it looks like a single line?

Comment: Hello jason, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please give us bit more? It's very had to understand what you want to achieve. If you could tell us what you have tried as will, that would help getting you a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to review [the types of questions](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which should and should not be asked. Specifically what to [avoid asking](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). **Simple "how to" question" are customarily not desirable.**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call those paths.  When you say "path" in the context of graphics software, you are typically referring to vector-based paths.  This looks a lot more like two raster-based lines.

Use your `Brush Tool` and set the hardness to 100%
[image: brush]

Then, while hovering over the already drawn lines, use the `[` or `]` key to adjust the width of the brush until the brush matches the line's thickness (`[`= smaller, `]`= larger).

Hold `ALT (Option)` and click within the "path" to select its color.

Draw the remaining section in by hand.